# Put query results into custom object instead of generic sObject

Tags: apex, soql

I've seen in a few places it seems likes people are directly mapping their query over to a custom apex object. E.g.

`MyObject myObject = [SELECT fields FROM object WHERE cond];`

Is this possible? If so, what does my class need to look like for everything to map correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is actually very common, but with `SObjects` instead of Apex classes.

I have a feeling that if you look harder at those examples, they'll all be SObjects like `Account`, `Contact`, `SomeCustomObject__c`, etc...

While the official documentation does say that a SOQL query will return a `List<SObject>`<sup>1</sup>, the result of a SOQL query can be automatically converted to a List of a more specific type.

For example, the following is very common (and perfectly valid)
`List<Opportunity> myOpps = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity LIMIT 10];`

While not really advised<sup>2</sup>, you can extend this to assigning a single variable of your target SObject type (provided that your query returns exactly one record)

<sup>1: ...unless you throw in a `GROUP BY` clause and/or use some aggregate functions like `SUM()`, in which case the query will return a `List<AggregateResult>`</sup>
<sup>2: Assigning a query to a single variable instead of a collection will cause an exception if your query returns anything other than one row. 0 rows or 2+ rows = error. The safest way to go about this is to *always* assign the result of a query to a collection</sup>